# Expiring JWT tokens in Flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask, jwt

I've been using [`flask-jwt-extended`](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for my application and one of the problems I had was logging a session out and making sure the token is not usable anymore.

I've based my solution on the [Blacklist and Token Revoking documentation page](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_and_token_revoking.html) with a custom `RevokedToken` model:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()


class RevokedToken(db.Model):
    """
    Model is used as a storage to keep invalid/revoked tokens.
    Currently used for log out functionality.
    """
    __tablename__ = 'revoked_tokens'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    jti = db.Column(db.String(120))

    @classmethod
    def is_jti_blacklisted(cls, jti):
        query = cls.query.filter_by(jti=jti).first()
        return bool(query)
```

Logout resource:

```
class LogoutResource(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def post(self):
        jti = get_raw_jwt()['jti']

        # invalidate access token
        revoked_token = RevokedToken(jti=jti)
        session.add(revoked_token)
        session.commit()

        return {}, 200
```

And the `token_in_blacklist_loader()` `jwt` function:

```
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

jwt = JWTManager(app)

@jwt.token_in_blacklist_loader
def check_if_token_in_blacklist(decrypted_token):
    jti = decrypted_token['jti']
    return models.RevokedToken.is_jti_blacklisted(jti)
```

This looks straightforward enough, but, as we are talking about authentication, I thought I would ask if anyone sees any flaws or potential improvements to this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell,

- This looks like a pretty solid implementation of blacklisting.
- I can't see any obvious code mistakes.

I you are worried about security it can be wise to check the [corresponding OWASP documentation](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/JSON_Web_Token_(JWT)_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java)

*This is for Java, but the security considerations should be similar*